# How to retrieve a custom object when clicking a line in a matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Matplotlib has pickable objects which return data about the picked object.

Example (taken from [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html)):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))
def onclick(event):
     print('%s click: button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f' %
           ('double' if event.dblclick else 'single', event.button,
            event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata))
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

But next to retrieving data like `event.x` or `event.ydata` I would like to retrieve a reference to a custom object. Where each different plotted point returns a different reference. Is this possible?

## Edit:

To clarify, let's say I have list of many objects:

```
objects = [SomeObject() for _ in range(10**10)]
```

Each of them can be converted to some value which I plot:

```
points = [obj.to_value() for obj in objects]
ax.plot(points)
```

Now when I click such a plotted value I want to be able to access the object it was derived from. Furthermore, I would prefer it if the `event` passed to the `onclick(...)` method would have a reference to this object, instead of having to search through the list with objects.

Comment: I guess you just need to scroll down a bit on the linked page to find the [Object picking](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html#object-picking) section. Apart, it's not too clear what you want to accomplish here, so maybe you want to add your "custom object" to the code and explain the problem you have using it.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear, I've edited my answer in the hope to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific about what you call an "custom object". Do these objects have coordinates that match the ones of the points that are plotted on the graph?

If so, I believe the general approach would be to simply loop through your list of custom objects, and find the one that has the same coordinates as the ones returned by the `click event` (with a reasonable error margin).

Comment: With "custom object" I just mean any possible object in the python language. They do not necessarily have to have coordinates that match those of the `click event`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to use a `pick_event` as detailed in the [Object picking](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html#object-picking) section in the documentation.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class SomeObject():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = np.random.rand()

    def to_value(self):
        return self.value

    def __repr__(self):
        return "This is object with value {}".format(self.to_value())

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

objects = [SomeObject() for _ in range(10)]

points = [obj.to_value() for obj in objects]
ax.plot(points, "o-", picker=5) 

def onpick(event):
    ind = event.ind[0]
    obj = objects[ind]
    print(obj)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```